# Angular & RxJs Poerators : How to overide object value with another request observable (pipe / mergeMap ?)

Tags: angular, rxjs, operators

I have an Api server from which I manage to get a list of "Manufacturer" object using the following services :

```
export class ManufacturerService {

  private manufacturers: Manufacturer[] = [];
  private manufacturersSubject = new Subject<Manufacturer[]>();
  manufacturersSubject$ = this.manufacturersSubject.asObservable();

  getManufacturersFromRest() {
    this.manufacturers=[];
    this.apiService.getEntriesFromRest('manufacturers').subscribe(
    (data: Manufacturer[]) => { 
            this.manufacturers=data; 
            this.manufacturersSubject.next(this.manufacturers.slice());
        },
    (error) => {...}
    );
  }
}

export class ApiService {

  private baseEndpoint = 'http://fooo/bar/';
  private maxTime = 10000;

  public getEntriesFromRest (option: string): any {
    return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(this.baseEndpoint + option)
        .pipe(
            timeout(this.maxTime),
            catchError(this.handleError),
            map((data) => data['hydra:member'])
        );
  }
}
```

My manufacturer model looks like this :

```
export class Manufacturer
 {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public companyname: string,
    ...
    public country: Country,
    public stateprov: State,
    public logo: Logo,
  ) {}
}
```

But my Api server does not answer Country / State nor Logo type for the corresponding fields, but the address to make arequest to get the associated objects, i.e.

```
/bar/coutries/{id}
/bar/states/{id}
/bar/logos/{id]
```

How can I use RxJs operators to overide manufacturers Observable (country, states and logo fields) with other http request answers ? Something like:

```
this.apiService.getEntriesFromRest('manufacturers').pipe(
 mergeMap((manufacturer) => {manufacturer.country = this.countryService.getCountryfromRest(manufacturer.country.split('/').pop());},
 mergeMap((manufacturer) => {manufacturer.state = this.stateService.getSatefromRest(manufacturer.state.split('/').pop());},
 mergeMap((manufacturer) => {manufacturer.logo = this.logoService.getLogofromRest(manufacturer.logo.split('/').pop());},
)
.subscribe(
    (data: Manufacturer[]) => { 
            this.manufacturers=data; 
            this.manufacturersSubject.next(this.manufacturers.slice());
        },
```

thank you for your help,

EDIT 1 :

```
  getManufacturersFromRest() {
    this.manufacturers=[];
    this.apiService.getEntriesFromRest('manufacturers').pipe(
        switchMap(
            manufacturer => forkJoin({
                country: this.countrystateService.getCountryObsFromRest(+manufacturer['country'].split('/').pop()),
                state: this.countrystateService.getStateObsFromRest(+manufacturer['state'].split('/').pop()),
                logo: this.logoService.getLogoObsFromRest(+manufacturer['country'].split('/').pop()),
            }).pipe(
                map(results => ({ ...manufacturer as Manufacturer, ...results }))
            )
        )
    ).subscribe(
        (manufacturers: Manufacturer[]) => { 
this.manufacturers=manufacturers;
this.manufacturersSubject.next(this.manufacturers.slice());},
        (error) => {
            this.manufacturerSubject.next(error);
            return throwError(error);
        }
    );
  }
```

EDIT 2 :

```
  getManufacturersFromRest() {
    this.manufacturers=[];
    this.apiService.getEntriesFromRest('manufacturers').subscribe(
        (manufacturers: Manufacturer[]) => { 
            this.manufacturers=manufacturers;
            this.manufacturersSubject.next(this.manufacturers.slice());
        },
        (error) => {
            this.manufacturerSubject.next(error);
            return throwError(error);
        }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution if it can help

```
getManufacturersFromRest() {
    this.apiService.getEntriesFromRest('manufacturers').pipe(
            mergeMap( (manufacts: any[]) => forkJoin(
                manufacts.map((manufact: any) => forkJoin({
                        country: this.countrystateService.getCountryObsFromRest(manufact['country']),
                        stateprov: this.countrystateService.getStateObsFromRest(manufact['stateprov']),
                        logo: this.logoService.getLogoObsFromRest(manufact['logo']),
                    }).pipe(
                        map(results => ({ ...manufact, ...results}))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ).subscribe(
        (manufacturers: Manufacturer []) => {
            this.manufacturers=manufacturers;
            this.manufacturersSubject.next(this.manufacturers.slice());
        },
        (error) => {
            this.manufacturersSubject.next(error);
            return throwError(error);
        },
        () => {console.log('Complete');}
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the `Manufacturer` object from the first request, you could do something like this:

```js
this.apiService.getEntriesFromRest('manufacturers').pipe(
  switchMap(
    m => forkJoin({
      country: this.service.getCountry(m),
      state: this.service.getState(m),
      /* ... */
      logo: this.service.getLogo(m),
    }).pipe(
      map(results => ({ ...m, ...results }))
    )
  )
).subscribe((m) => /* manufacturer with all the needed data */)
```

`forkJoin` can be given an object whose keys map to observables. In return, after all the observables will have completed, you'll get an object with the **same keys**, but instead of observables, the keys map to their resulted values.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I try your solution (please see edit), but the requests inside the forkJoin are not triggered.! what did I miss?

Comment: Are you sure that the Observables emit at least once and complete?

Comment: yes, Edit 2 works perfectly (but without the field replacement) and on firefox network anaylser, I can see the Manufacvturer request for both Edit1 & Edit2 code with code 200 answer and the Object table. 
getEntriesFromRest return a any[]. switchMap should automaticaaly split the array right? and for each element performs the 3 requests ?
and what is strange is that I do not have any console error

Comment: Try to put the complete handler as well. Does it log something? I think the problem is at observable-level

Comment: I think the manufacturer parameter in the forkJoin is not defined... How can I integrate a console.log to check?

Comment: Add the third parameter to “subscribe”, which is the complete handler: “() => console.log(‘complete’)”

Comment: I changed the +manufacturer['xxxx'].split('/').pop() by 1 to test, and in this case request are made and the forkJoin results seems to be ok, BUT the map(results => ({ ...manufacturer as Manufacturer, ...results })), seems not to work as I now have a "this.manufacturers.slice() is not a function" error

Comment: Not sure.. you should start from a smaller problem, e.g: `forkJoin({ a: of('a'), b: of('b') })` and then try to alter it depending on your requirements. Also, if needed, I think we should move this discussion to a chat.

Comment: Do you know a chat support please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213161/discussion-between-andrei-gtej-and-alexglvr).